# Fix duplicate entries in CodeIgniter Session Database

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, session

I have multiple duplicates in my CodeIgniter session database table. How can I fix this?

I tried the following:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Session extends CI_Session 
{

/**
* Update an existing session
*
* @access    public
* @return    void
*/
    function sess_update()
    {
       // skip the session update if this is an AJAX call!
       if ( !IS_AJAX )
       {
           parent::sess_update();
       }
} 

}

/* End of file MY_Session.php */
/* Location: ./application/libraries/MY_Session.php */
```

and this config.php

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 600;
```

I'm loading the `MY_Session` Library in the autoloader but I don't know if I have to change anything else.

Comment: What do you mean 'multiple duplicates'? Do you mean the rows are being duplicated? And does this cause sessions to fail?

Comment: @JohnP yes i do have problems with it. the session is not working!
http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/729/4194474904.png

Comment: Does it not work at all or does it stop working after a certain period or action?

Comment: it does not work at all...